# Getting inner text of divs with same class but with a filter

Tags: javascript

I am applying this below code to the console to get information out of a web page:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName( 'company_name' ),
innerHTMLs = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i )
innerHTMLs.push( elements[i].innerHTML );
console.log( innerHTMLs );
```

What should I do to make sure that if there isn't an innerHTML of a given element I get 0 or null?

Regards

Comment: Just add an `if` statement?

Comment: I am just starting to learn Javascript and am completely lost on how to do just that :/

Comment: @AleksandraKowalczyk Then I wonder how you got to the point of code. 
Check out [MDN - Learn Web-Development](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn). You should start at the very beginning and work your way up.

Comment: @AleksandraKowalczyk Are you aware, that `++i` increments the counter _**before**_ using it in the logic? I can imagine, that you maybe want to use `i++` since arrays start at an index of 0, and with `++i` you skip the first Entry in your array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName( 'company_name' ),
innerHTMLs = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ){
  innerHTMLs.push( elements[i].innerHTML?elements[i].innerHTML:0 );
console.log( innerHTMLs );
}
```

The code `elements[i].innerHTML?elements[i].innerHTML:0` uses a `ternary operator` this simulates an inline if statement where the part before the `?` defines the conditional statement, the part after that is the value which is returned if the statement is true. The part after the `:` is what is returned if the condition evaluates to false.

If you would write this in full it would become the following (since you are new to javascript this is also good to know):

```
if (elements[i].innerHTML) {
 innerHTMLs.push(elements[i].innerHTML);
} else {
 innerHTMLs.push(0);
}
```

---

**Additional Information**

There are still a few things that can/have to be changed, to make it work better.

- When declaring a counter (*`i` in this case*) you want to use `let` instead of `var`. In your Example it won't make any difference. But the difference comes, when you want to use another loop in the same scope. `var` is scoped to a whole area, either global, or in a function, while `let` scopes the variable on block level, which means with `let` your counter with the name *`i`* is only declared in the for-loop. This is desirable since you clearly don't want to use another letter or somtheing like *`ii`*, *`iii`* and so on, for your counter. This makes code more readable and is less likely to created unexpected behaviour.

  ```
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName( 'company_name' ),
      innerHTMLs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ){
    innerHTMLs.push( elements[i].innerHTML?elements[i].innerHTML:0 );
    console.log( innerHTMLs );
  }
  ```
- Using Increment after Usage: Your decleration of `++i` means, that you increment the counter before using it. In some cases this is quite useful, but in this case, it jumps over your first Item in your `elements`-array. For your purpose, use `i++`, so the counter will be `0` when going through the first iteration. Having it `0` on first iteration is important, since arrays start their indexing at `0` not `1`.

  ```
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName( 'company_name' ),
      innerHTMLs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ){
    innerHTMLs.push( elements[i].innerHTML?elements[i].innerHTML:0 );
    console.log( innerHTMLs );
  }
  ```

Comment: The only thing is, I wanted to get all of the results and in those cases where is isn't the inner HTML of a given div I wanted it to be represented by 0 or something and not cut from the list entirely. Is something like that possible?

Comment: @AleksandraKowalczyk see the edit for the updated explanation i added, 0 will be added in this case :)

Comment: @AleksandraKowalczyk This is what the code (should) do. `elements[i].innerHTML?elements[i].innerHTML:0` means `if(elements[i].innerHTML){ elements[i].innerHTML}else{0}`.

Comment: @Pavan additionally we may want to use `let` instead of `var` for the increment. For the sake of scope

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.innerHTML.trim() != ""` to check if the trimmed (remove all whitespaces at the start and end of the string doesn't equal an empty string. This will return true if the string is nog empty.

For example:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i ) {
  if(elements[i].innerHTML.trim() != "") {
    innerHTMLs.push( elements[i].innerHTML );
    console.log( innerHTMLs );
  }
}
```